# Show that a polynomial is inside $\Bbb Q^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Observe the following polynomial over the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[x]$:
$$f(x)=x^5+1$$
We can rewrite $f$ as $f(x)=(x-1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$. Now for showing that $f$ is not reducible, $(x-1) \in \Bbb Q[x]^*$. Now I know that $\Bbb Q[x]^*=\Bbb Q^*$ but I can't use it...

Comment: (a) Your factorisation is wrong (b) if you factorise something into proper factors it can't be irredcucible, can it?

Comment: Title: a polynomial is not inside $\Bbb Q^*$, except for trivial cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factorisation is slightly off; it should be
$$f(x)=(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$$
The existence of a linear factor already shows by definition that $f$ is reducible.

Comment: Oh yes true, thank you!